# BYFN - How to set up a Hyperledger Fabric network without using the CLI container?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to set up the BYFN Hyperledger Fabric (v1.4.1) network by manually executing the commands, as opposed to running the script byfn.sh, given here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#start-the-network

I observed that the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d`
spins up one container per peer and orderer node. But it also spins up a container for a CLI, through which all subsequent commands are run. By examining the docker-compose-cli.yaml file it is also evident that the filesystem of the CLI container contains the crypto material for all the peers and the orderer. This leads me to the following two questions:

1. Can one not run the subsequent  commands for network setup (such channel creation, joining a channel, chaincode installation etc.) by 'exec'-ing into the Docker container of the corresponding peers?
2. Is it a good practice to spin up a single container which has the crypto material of all network components in one location, as is the case with the CLI container? Won't such a design, when adopted in production, compromise the private keys of the organisations involved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely setup your network without using a cli container. That's just for a shortcut to access multiple peers using a single container. It's basically just a container in which you pass certificates of all the peers or orderers to access to the network. So whatever you are doing from cli you can do seperately from other containers. Now coming back to your questions:

1. Can one not run the subsequent commands for network setup (such channel creation, joining a channel, chaincode installation etc.) by 'exec'-ing into the Docker container of the corresponding peers?

   **Yes, you can definitely do that the only requirement is you must set the environment variables accordingly.**
2. Is it a good practice to spin up a single container which has the crypto material of all network components in one location, as is the case with the CLI container? Won't such a design, when adopted in production, compromise the private keys of the organisations involved?

   **Yes, it will surely be a problem for a production setup. You can't be having a single cli for your peers and orderers. As I have already told you can do everything without a cli container but if you still want a cli then you can have different cli for your orderer container and your peer container.**